# Symfony2 Avalanche_Imagine Bundle Chain

Tags: symfony

I have create a new class that inherits LoaderInterface. My objective is to apply a watermark and then resize the image to be a thumbnail... 
Anyone have an idea how do this? Problem is that my class return load a filter type and cant return more than 1 filter types... so how create a chain?

Thanks a lot.

Here is my sample code

```
namespace Avalanche\Bundle\ImagineBundle\Imagine\Filter\Loader;

use Imagine\Image\Box;
use Imagine\Image\ManipulatorInterface;
use Imagine\Filter\Basic\Thumbnail;
use \Imagine\Filter\Basic\Paste;

class ThumbnailWatermarkFilterLoader implements LoaderInterface
{
    const WATERMARK_IMAGE_PATH = "watermark_image";
    const WATERMARK_FONT_PATH = "font";

    public function load(array $options = array())
    {
        $mode = $options['mode'] === 'inset' ?
            ManipulatorInterface::THUMBNAIL_INSET :
           ManipulatorInterface::THUMBNAIL_OUTBOUND;

           list($width, $height) = $options['size'];

           $watermark = new \Imagine\Gd\Image(imagecreatefrompng($options[self::WATERMARK_IMAGE_PATH]));
           $point = new \Imagine\Image\Point($width / 2  , $height /2);

           $thumb = new Paste($watermark, $point);


          return $thumb;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for exactly the same, but didn't find a source that was useful.
So I went and created my own watermark-filter. You can use it if you want.

I have an example-configuration showing you how to combine the watermark with the thumbnail-filter.

https://github.com/SimonSimCity/WatermarkFilterBundle